# Error Connecting to Azure Analysis Server in SQL Server Mgmt Studio: 'WinInet cannot redirect.'

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, ssms, azure-analysis-services

I am following [this article](https://www.sanjaybhagia.com/2018/11/12/accessing-azure-analysis-services-models-using-net-core/) to use Azure Analysis Services. I am trying to connect to an Azure Analysis server in SQL Server Management Studio, using the 'Active Directory - Universal with MFA support' option. A window for my organization's sign-in page opens, and I sign in with my credentials, then I get the following error message:

> The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: WinInet cannot redirect. 
>   This error code might also be returned by a custom protocol handler. (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)

Comment: You could [read this case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/56104/the-browser-based-authentication-dialog-failed-to-1.html) if it is worked for you

Comment: Also please try from another network and not using proxy. In many situations it may be a corporate proxy that is blocking access to services / URIs. Although Azure Analysis Services uses HTTPS as transport protocol, a corporate proxy may still have issues with that.

Comment: The connection succeeded when I did it at home with proxy turned off. But when I did it by connecting to a mobile hotspot on my phone at work, the error still occurs.